# Why do my React App reload after fetching data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

After getting user email and password and getting access to enter, app goes to user profile page and goes after that to sign in form again.
That happened when I added .then(data => ...). One more issue is that I'm using POST method but after signing in at first time I can see email and password in URL and it stays there after going to sign in form again. And again if I remove .then(data => ...) everything works fine with POST method.

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
            email: this.state.signInEmail,
            password: this.state.signInPassword 
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
               if (data === 'success') {
                   this.props.onRouteChange('home');
               }
        });
    };
```

This function is for Sign In button. .onRouteChange('home') just shows what components should app show.

Comment: how do you trigger you onSubmitSignIn function ?

Comment: <input
type="submit"             
onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn} 
             value="Sign in"/>

Comment: where onRouteChange function is coming from? is it your function or a library function?  if it yours - what is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the whole thing but one thing I can help with the submit is to stop the default behavior of the form:

```
onSubmitSignIn = (event) => {
  // ...
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Try this first then go figure other things later.

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much! But why did it help?